# POST operations returning a "Not Found" error

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, post, asp.net-core-webapi, crud

I'm trying to develop multi-platform app that uses a WebAPI uploaded on my server.

Here is the code for GET/POST:

```
public async void post_async(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {       

        Console.WriteLine("POST");


        try
        {
            HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();

            var uri = new Uri("https://mywebsite");

            var item = new users_model { username = "prove_username", email = "prove_mail", password = "prove_pwd", ranking = "prove_ranking"};
            

            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(item, Formatting.Indented);
            var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            var httpContent = new StringContent(json);

            var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(uri, httpContent);
            var message = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            Console.WriteLine($"STATUS CODE POST:    " + response.StatusCode);
            Console.WriteLine($"REQUEST MESSAGE POST:    " + response.RequestMessage);
            Console.WriteLine($"CONTENT POST:    " + message);
            //Console.WriteLine($"DATA POST:    " + item.username);


        }
        catch (Exception er)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"ERROR: " + er.ToString());

        }


    }

    async void get_async(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {

        try
        {
            HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();

            var uri = new Uri("https://mywebsite");
            var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(uri);
            var message = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            Console.WriteLine($"STATUS CODE GET:    " + response.StatusCode);
            Console.WriteLine($"REQUEST MESSAGE GET:    " + response.RequestMessage);
            Console.WriteLine($"CONTENT GET:    " + message);


        }
        catch (Exception er)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"ERROR: " + er.ToString());

        }

    }
```

Here is the code of controller:

```
public class users_model
{
    public string username { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string password { get; set; }
    public string ranking { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the code of Web Api:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<List<users_model>> getAllUsers ()
    {

        FirebaseClient firebase = new FirebaseClient("https://myFirebaseSite/");

        Items = new List<users_model>();
        Items = (await firebase.Child("users").OnceAsync<users_model>()).Select(item => new users_model

        {
            username = item.Object.username,
            email = item.Object.email,
            password = item.Object.password,
            ranking = item.Object.ranking

        }).ToList();

        return Items;
    }

   [HttpPost]
   public IActionResult addUser([FromBody] users_model new_user)
        {

            return Ok($"post ok. username: " + new_user.username);
        }
```

If I call get_async => no problem
If I call post_async I get "NotFound".
If I use [ActionName("void_name")] instead of [HttpPost] and [HttpGet] I get "UnsupportedMediaType"

I even tried to use NUGet "RestSharp" but I got same issue.
Please help me, it's 3 days I cannot find how to fix the issue :(

Comment: your model is users_model but in add user you use userModel? is that a typo?

Comment: `public IActionResult addUser([FromBody] userModel new_user)`

you defined your class as `user_model` and here are referring to it as `userModel`, perhaps you can try this:

`public IActionResult addUser([FromBody] user_model new_user)`?

Comment: Code of Web Api and code of the app are in 2 different projects. So I wrote same model for Web Api and for the app. I followed this tutorial https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/webservices-todorest/ but I have this issue. Very strange. Any ideas?

Comment: You should not [return void in async methods](https://rules.sonarsource.com/csharp/tag/async-await/RSPEC-3168).

Comment: Can you explain more please?

Comment: UnsupportedMediaType: Did you also try posting `content` instead `httpContent`? NotFound: indicates posting to a wrong uri (see the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-in-aspnet-web-api#routing-variations)). Also note that you might want to use the ActionName attribute in addition to the HttpPost attribute, not instead.